# List partition labels from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, partition, disk

Is there a command that will list all partitions along with their labels? `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` don't show labels by default.

EDIT: (as per comment below) I'm talking about ext2 labels - those that you can set in `gparted` upon partitioning.

EDIT2: The intent is to list *unmounted* partitions (so I know which one to mount).

Comment: Labels? What's a label? Are you talking about ext2 labels? Those have nothing to do with partition tables per se.

Comment: Hi @Chris Jester-Young, thanks for your comment! I have tried to clarify above - yes, I believe it is ext2 labels I'm talking about... Cheers!

Comment: Partitions don't have labels, but file systems do. You need a combination of tools to do that. The `blkid` tool can tell you label of a known partition. But to find the partition you would have to loop over the output of fdisk.

Comment: @Keith, as a side note, I'd like to add that the new [GPT partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries) have a **name** field which is similar to filesystem labels.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

With udev, You can use

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
```

to show the symlinks by label to at least *some* partition device nodes.

Not sure what the logic of inclusion is, possibly the existence of a label.

Comment: At least on my machine, it is indeed only the filesystems with labels that get linked in there, as confirmed(?) by using Alan Kuras' `mount -l` suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Ilkka - thanks for your answer! Indeed, `ls -la /dev/disk/by-label` seems to show labels of unmounted partitions; so that solves my problem, I guess... Although, I really would have preferred an option for `fdisk` or `parted` instead :) Cheers!

Comment: For me, my swap partition and mounted partitions are not shown, but that may just be coincidence. Anyhow, `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid` worked for me.

Comment: On my system `/dev/disk/by-label` is unpopulated when the `initramfs` mounts root fs.

Comment: Answer is > 10 years old.  Things have changed since?

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04) there's no `/dev/disk/by-label` 
OTOH: there's `/dev/disk/by-partlabel`

Comment: @arielf: it's there on Ubuntu 18, but ext2 labels from `dmsetup` devices don't show by this method (nor by lsblk). They only show with `e2label`.

Answer (score 209):

### with [`lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)

For instance, the command

```
lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid
```

outputs:

```
NAME                           MOUNTPOINT     LABEL         SIZE UUID
sda                                                         1.4T
├─sda1                         /boot          boot          953M f557b9f0-edb5-42bb-94d8-27bc03c3c2c7
├─sda2                                                     46.6G 727fa348-8804-4773-ae3d-f3e176d12dac
│ └─sda2_crypt (dm-0)                                      46.6G P1kvJI-5iqv-s9gJ-8V2H-2EEO-q4aK-sx4aDi
│   ├─debian_crypt-swap (dm-1) [SWAP]                         2G 3f9f24d7-86d1-4e21-93e9-f3c181d05cf0
│   ├─debian_crypt-tmp (dm-2)  /tmp           tmp             5G 93fc8219-f985-45fb-bd5c-2c7940a7512d
│   ├─debian_crypt-home (dm-3) /home          home            6G 12e8566c-8f0f-45ec-8524-6d9d9ee91eae
│   └─debian_crypt-root (dm-4) /              root         33.6G 9685570b-4c9e-43ea-815e-49d10dc7a1bf
├─sda3                                                    651.9G d3e0436c-85f6-45c6-9d8f-28b79ee06102
│ └─crypt_gusto (dm-8)         /media/Gusto   Gusto       651.9G 0c084508-cb8b-4b61-832d-6b85273f33c4
├─sda4                                                        1K
├─sda5                                                      298G 5063da5f-9b68-43de-914c-32b89622bcc8
│ └─crypt_kabi (dm-7)          /media/Kabi    Kabi          298G e6a0b66c-8fe9-4e7b-9d54-7b2b430e109d
├─sda6                                                    213.6G 5129d860-bb41-4393-b4b1-f8af53d9155d
│ └─crypt_zami (dm-6)          /media/Zami    Zami        213.6G 19101155-6070-4f37-b39d-19f28867c66b
├─sda7                         /media/Server  Server       85.6G a9f4dae5-901c-4f49-bb30-592de3000713
└─sda8                                                    100.6G dc7f4586-a33d-4707-98e9-8b55c559b0d2
  └─crypt_grafi (dm-5)         /media/Grafi   Grafi       100.6G 5e3242e1-ec7a-4806-92f7-88a126feea94
sdb                                                        14.5G
├─sdb1                                        DEBIAN_LIVE     3G 6bf4d915-2b62-444e-a2c8-16307769b5c2
├─sdb2                                                        2G 90ec6f73-8fdb-4c8d-aebd-cadd0f51b412
│ └─crypt_sdb2 (dm-10)         /mnt           data            2G 91e779dd-0a3f-40b2-8ad0-257d860541a6
└─sdb3                                        linux         9.5G 14a783a4-96dd-4a85-8de7-6e8eea230594
loop0                                                      1000M a3be80bf-0f2c-44ed-8de5-d60e3b19c01a
└─crypt_dropbox (dm-9)         /media/Dropbox Dropbox       998M 8461e2cf-ae17-449b-8ee5-29cc88688b8b
zram0                          [SWAP]                       250M f8254ae5-5ae6-4fda-b8ef-83f25c405894
zram1                          [SWAP]                       250M 7e7ed90d-731c-422a-bf9b-828f09b80502
```

You can specify plenty of columns in whatever order you like:

```
Available columns:
       NAME  device name
      KNAME  internal kernel device name
    MAJ:MIN  major:minor device number
     FSTYPE  filesystem type
 MOUNTPOINT  where the device is mounted
      LABEL  filesystem LABEL
       UUID  filesystem UUID
         RO  read-only device
         RM  removable device
      MODEL  device identifier
       SIZE  size of the device
      STATE  state of the device
      OWNER  user name
      GROUP  group name
       MODE  device node permissions
  ALIGNMENT  alignment offset
     MIN-IO  minimum I/O size
     OPT-IO  optimal I/O size
    PHY-SEC  physical sector size
    LOG-SEC  logical sector size
       ROTA  rotational device
      SCHED  I/O scheduler name
    RQ-SIZE  request queue size
       TYPE  device type
   DISC-ALN  discard alignment offset
  DISC-GRAN  discard granularity
   DISC-MAX  discard max bytes
  DISC-ZERO  discard zeroes data
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this tool! Note, this application works for regular users, but will show some info (including labels) only as root.

Comment: Will it show unmounted partitions also? If yes then it solves the question asked.

Comment: Yes. As you can see sdb1 and sdb3 aren't mounted.

Comment: or easier to remember `lsblk -f` which is equivalent to `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT`

Comment: @user689893 - no, that only happens on debian/ubuntu and derivatives. The point of `lsblk` is to be used by regular users so no need to su/sudo. Now, if that doesn't work for you, it's because your distro devs prolly missed something.

Comment: Easier to remember: `lsblk -fo +size`. It will list (or is equivalent to): `lsblk -o name,fstype,label,uuid,mountpoint,size`

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary.

Comment: Another variant: `lsblk -o +label,uuid` which lists **more** information. By the way,  @user689893 , I completely agree with @Dirk. I see no difference **at all**, with or without using `sudo` with this command (in Ubuntu 16.04.). Consequently, do not use sudo.

Comment: I needed root to see the LABEL.

Comment: Gave me EXACTLY what I needed to make my external HDD mounts persist across a restart. Depending on the phase of the moon and it's position vis-a-vis Venus, it would show up as sdb, sdg, or anything in between... Since I have 2 migratory external disks, things were always weird and using ls-d /dev/sd* to figure out which was which was annoying.

Comment: Doesn't work for ext2 labels though at least on `dmsetup` devices. Only shows VFAT and NTFS ones for me on Ubuntu 18 LTS. `e2label` works, but of course it's specific to that fs. (Don't ask why I tested on that old thing... it's because that's the only supported OS for HDDsuperclone.)

Answer (score 30):

There is a [**blkid**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html) command which may be what you are looking for. Results are similar to the following:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/mapper/vg_rootdisk-lv_var
/dev/mapper/vg_rootdisk-lv_var: LABEL="LV_VAR" UUID="08520908-03cd-4e42-a4e4-0f5a771be16c" TYPE="ext4"
```

One other option is to use the [**udevadm**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html) command, which likely will give you far more than you need:

```
$ sudo udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/mapper/vg_rootdisk-lv_var
```

Comment: This was the only suggestion so far that worked on ddwrt

Answer (score 16):

Try to use this command:

```
e2label /dev/sda2
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `mount -l`, it work's fine for me.

Comment: Hi @Alan Kuras - thanks and +1 for the answer! However, I want to list unmounted partitions - `mount -l` seems to show only mounted ones.. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

#### /dev/disk

In newer versions of the Linux kernel this info can now be found here under `/dev/disk`.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 300 Mar  4 18:43 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 140 Mar  4 18:21 by-label
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Mar  4 18:18 by-path
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 200 Mar  4  2015 by-uuid
```

So you can find it by `by-id`, `by-label`, `by-path` or by `by-uuid`.

- *by-id*

  ```
  $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jan 11 17:01 ata-Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7930H -> ../../sr0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Jan 11 17:01 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX1K0Q5 -> ../../sda
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX1K0Q5-part1 -> ../../sda1
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX1K0Q5-part2 -> ../../sda2
  ...
  ...
  ```
- *by-uuid*

  ```
  $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 xxxxxx -> ../../sda1
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 xxxxxx -> ../../dm-1
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 xxxxxx -> ../../dm-0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Jan 11 17:01 xxxxxx -> ../../dm-2
  ```

  Where the `xxxxxx` would be an actual UUID such as `5ece678c-1234-5678-12e3-88c06ec11111`.
- *by-label*

  ```
  $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:21 LABEL1 -> ../../sda4
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:17 LABEL2 -> ../../sda3
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:21 LABEL3 -> ../../sda6
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:42 LABEL4 -> ../../sda7
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:20 LABEL5 -> ../../sda5
  ```

  Where `LABEL1`,`LABEL2`,... etc are **label** which shows symbolic links to actual partition (e.g `/dev/sda3`).

Comment: To sort by partition name: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/ | sort -k10`

Answer (score 5):

This will not list all partitions but you can view and alter what you like with `tune2fs`.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
```

You can use a command such as this to get all the `/dev/sda*` devices.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo /dev/sda* /dev/mapper/fedora* | xargs -n 1 tune2fs -l'
```

Answer (score 4):

e2label didn't work for me with UDF filesystem labels. blkid did;

```
blkid -s LABEL -o value /dev/sdg1
```

Comment: this answer is potentially the more complete

Comment: This is perfect for WSL because e2label requires always sudo and there is no ``/dev/disk``.

Answer (score 4):

In a Linux terminal (console) type :

```
blkid
```

Followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The result is the list of block devices, each with LABEL and TYPE

Answer (score 4):

Very easy:

```
lsblk -fp
```

Description from the man page:

> ```
>   -f, --fs
>           Output info about filesystems.  This option is equivalent to -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,MOUNTPOINT.  The authoritative information about filesystems and raids is provided by the blkid(8) command.
>
>   -p, --paths
>           Print full device paths.
> ```

On both of the following distributions I have tested the command:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 (Ootpa)
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Result:

```
$ lsblk -fp      
NAME                            FSTYPE      LABEL    UUID                                MOUNTPOINT
/dev/nvme0n1
├─/dev/nvme0n1p1                vfat        BOOT     xxxx-7xxD                           /boot/efi
├─/dev/nvme0n1p2
├─/dev/nvme0n1p3                ntfs        Windows  22xxxxxxxx1222B3001
├─/dev/nvme0n1p4                ntfs        Recovery xxxx1222222xxxx1
├─/dev/nvme0n1p5                ext4                 xxxxxx-5xx9-4xxb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx1   /boot
├─/dev/nvme0n1p6
├─/dev/nvme0n1p7                ext4                 xxxxxx-6xxb-4xx6-xxd7-xxxxxxxxxxxx
└─/dev/nvme0n1p8                crypto_LUKS          xxxxxx-exx0-415a-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  └─/dev/mapper/lukslvm         LVM2_member          xxxxxx-lxxH-Rxxn-xxxx-xxxx1-xxxxxx
    ├─/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap swap                 xxxxxx-5xx9-4xxb-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  [SWAP]
    └─/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ext4                 xxxxxx-fxxa-4xxd-9e41-xxxxxxxxxxxx  /
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this command:

```
$ sudo udevadm info --query all --path /sys/block/sdb/sdb1 \
     | grep ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME
```

You can use the above to print all the block devices' info.

```
$ echo /sys/block/* | xargs -n 1 udevadm info --query all --path
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like, you can use my bash script for that purpose. It actually does a little more than you need, i. e. it will also show how much space is used.
Hope you like it :)
And I also hope that the output will be as neat as on my linux box...
(Note: it will only show *real* hardware like your HDDs and DVD-ROMs, but that's sufficient for my purposes.)

**Important note: This script might have to be run under `sudo`** ONCE because of `blkid`. At least on my distro, `blkid -o export` will **output nil** when run as regular user *after bootup*. This is because in the "regular user rendition" of `blkid`, data will actually be retrieved from a **cache file** (normally `/run/blkid/blkid.tab`), which is only writable by `root` and will thus require one run under `sudo` in order to get populated with current data.

```
#!/bin/bash
# LICENSE: GPL

if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
  if [[ ! -s /run/blkid/blkid.tab ]]; then
   # no cache file found when run as regular user
   # this will require one run under sudo to populate cache file
   echo -e "Cache file does not exist or is empty.\nPlease give your root password to continue:\n\n"   
   sudo blkid >/dev/null
  fi
fi

df -P |
sort  |
awk 'BEGIN {
             fmthdr = "%-12s%-22s%-10s\t%-5s\n"

         # since we want to use single quotes for showing label names, we had better
         # replace the problematic single quote character by its hex representation, "\x27"
             fmtlin_w_qu = "%-12s\x27%-17s\x27\t   %-10s\t%4s used\n"
             fmtlin_wo_qu = "%-12s%-17s\t   %-10s\t%4s used\n"

             printf fmthdr, " Device ",  "Volume Label", "File System", "Storage usage"
             printf fmthdr, "---------", "------------", "-----------", "-------------"
           }    
           /^\/dev\/[sh]/{
              lab = ""      # CLEAR lab w/every run (very important!)
              ("blkid -o export "$1" | grep LABEL | cut -f2 -d=") | getline lab
              ("blkid -o export "$1" | grep TYPE | cut -f2 -d=") | getline fs
              if (lab == "") {
                lab = "<none>"
                fmtlin = fmtlin_wo_qu
              }
              else
                fmtlin = fmtlin_w_qu

              printf fmtlin, $1, lab, fs, $5
           }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use also `lsblk` mentioned above, but I find the following options better suiting:

```
sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,tran,fstype,label,size
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how I get the fslabel of the fsroot partition as a regular user. This page helped me to succeed. Was not easy. Many commands only work with sudo, but /etc/mtab and /dev/disk/by-label are readable as regular user.

Here is the bash code:

```bsh
test=`cat /etc/mtab|grep " / "`
test=${test%% *}
test=${test##*/}
test=`ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/|grep $test`
test=${test%% ->*}
test=${test##* }
```